# Using new Ruby pattern matching to check if a hash has certain keys

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching

I want to use the new Ruby 3 feature in this very simple case. I know it must be possible but I have not figured it out from the documentation.

Given a hash, I want to check that it has certain keys. I don't mind if it has others in addition. And I want to do this with pattern matching (or know that it is impossible.) I also don't want to use a case statement which seems overkill.

```
{name: "John", salary: 12000, email: "john@email.com" }
```

1. Raise an error if the hash does not have name, and email as strings and salary as a number.
2. Use the contruct in an if or other conditional?
3. And what if the hash has strings as keys (which is what I get from JSON.parse) ?

   {"name" => "John", "salary" => 12000, "email" => "john@email.com" }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `=>` operator:

```
h = {name: "John", salary: 12000, email: "john@email.com" }
h => {name: String, salary: Numeric, email: String} # => nil
```

With an additional pair (`test: 0`):

```
h[:test] = 0
h => {name: String, salary: Numeric, email: String} # => nil
```

Without the `:name` key:

```
h.delete :name
h => {name: String, salary: Numeric, email: String} # key not found: :name (NoMatchingPatternKeyError)
```

With the `:name` key but the class of its value shouldn't match:

```
h[:name] = 1
h => {name: String, salary: Numeric, email: String} # String === 1 does not return true (NoMatchingPatternKeyError)
```

A strict match:

```
h[:name] = "John"
h => {name: String, salary: Numeric, email: String} # => rest of {:test=>0} is not empty
```

The `in` operator returns a boolean value instead of raising an exception:

```
h = {name: "John", salary: 12000, email: "john@email.com" }
h in {name: String, salary: Numeric, email: String} # => true
h[:name] = 1
h in {name: String, salary: Numeric, email: String} # => false
```

Comment: Thanks! So the only way other than a case statement is catching the exception. There's no "if" contruct?

Comment: Use the `in` operator if you want a boolean value.

Comment: I hate that they chose the Hash rocket to act as the operator in this case. Because `{h => {name: String, salary: Numeric, email: String}}` is still valid syntax but also completely different than `h => {name: String, salary: Numeric, email: String}`. I would have definitely preferred a distinctly different infix operator especially since pattern matching is so useful for Hash

Comment: @engineersmnky: True. At least they found a good (alternative) use for `in`.

Comment: @cremno true since no rubyist would support the use of `for x in arr` so `in` is a fairly safe bet :). Since ruby isn't functional and doesn't necessarily need a pipe (left side curry), other than maybe for a `Symbol#to_proc`, I would actively support the use of [tag:elixir]'s `|>` operator for pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

"I also don't want to use a case statement which seems overkill."  `case` is just the syntax for pattern matching. AFAIK it is not the same as a `case when`, it's a `case in`.

```
h = {name: "John", salary: 12000, email: "john@email.com", other_stuff: [1] } 
case h
  in {name: String, salary: Integer, email: String}
    puts "matched"
  else
    raise "#{h} not matched"
end
```